# Relative path to access database

Tags: r, database

I hope some one here can point me on the right direction.
I am trying to connect to an access database from R without hardcoding the path to it. For instance this works when I write the path:

```
library(RODBC)
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(DBI)
library(tibble)

myDB <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, 
*.accdb)};DBQ=C:/Users/myfolder/Desktop/R_Connection.accdb")

 #But this doesn't work. I put the database path in 'dbpath' but for some
 #reason 'dbpath' isn't recognized.

dbpath <- paste0(getwd(),"/R_Connection.accdb")
print(dbpath)
myDB <- odbcDriverConnect(paste0(""Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, 
*.accdb)};DBQ="",dbpath))
```

Comment: as it is more a programming question it would be better placed in stackoverflow forum by the way.

Answer (score 0):

you should be more specific by this does not work, like by providding the error messge. It's probably your double quote `"` from which you need to escape to paste the string. paste0 is confused. You can do so with `\"` or using a single quote`'` and put the second quote at the end like so:

`myDB <- odbcDriverConnect(paste0("'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=",dbpath,"'"))`

Comment: I left the double quotation marks by mistake because I was trying it with an outside program. However, this suggestion is not working for me. I get the error saying that it cannot connect to odbc driver

Answer (score 0):

This code works. Strangely that's how I was running it earlier and it didn't work. Started a new R session and it now works like a charm. Thanks for checking into it R. Prost.

```
  myDB <- odbcDriverConnect(paste0("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, 
  *.accdb)};DBQ=",dbpath))
```

Comment: ah so you didn't need the added quotes i usually also connect likes this: `con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),  .connection_string=paste0("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=",my_file))` then use collect or run directly my dbplyr on the connection con with tbl